# Is there MediaWiki API to convert mediawiki text to HTML?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

Is there any [MediaWIki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) API where I can submit entire (potentially very large) mediawiki text (for wikipedia article) that will give me HTML that is exactly the same as HTML article viewed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/) for the english language?

Comment: 1) Probably not. 2) Wikipedia article wikitext is hardly ever self-contained; it's full of references to templates, and you need the source of those templates (and any templates they reference, etc.) to render the page. 3) I believe this is a "recommendation question" and therefore off-topic for SO.

Comment: This is not recommendation question but a question about programming related to mediawiki API. Recommendation question would be do you recommend to use API A as opposed to API B.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`action=parse`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse) for this. I'm not sure what the limits are, though you might consider sending the `text` in the body of a POST request, instead of in the URL of a GET request.

Answer (score 3):

What svick said is the standard method. Alternatively you can use the [Parsoid API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Transforms/post_transform_wikitext_to_html_title_revision) which returns different HTML (but it will look the same).

Unlike `action=parse`, this is not part of MediaWiki; if you want to use it for your own wiki, see [its documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid) on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a mediawiki api but you can use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert mediawiki text to html or an other format.